# Is it possible to select an element based on the current page using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

considering I have a single css file for my entire website (and that doing so is an usual technique), I was wondering if there is a way to select website-wide attributes like `body` (or any other attribute in fact) according to the current page using only css.

Something like

```
body:in('index.html') {
    some properties;
}

body:in('contact.html') {
    other properties;
}
```

Again, css only. I know the simple solutions using things like php, js, jquery...

Comment: You could just give the body tag a different id or class name on the page and style it up like that.

Comment: Without adding anything to the DOM via some means (like the ones you've mentioned), no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Selectors have no information about the document beyond what is presented in the DOM tree, and the DOM does not expose information about the page according to its file name, URL, or any other such properties.

Historically there was a `@document` at-rule for querying the current URL, but it was removed from the [Conditional Rules Level 3 module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional). The most likely reason for this is the lack of cross-vendor implementations, as the only known implementation exists in Gecko, as [`@-moz-document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document). It's so bad, that the only uses for it that you'll spot in the wild are *not* to apply CSS based on a certain page, but solely as a CSS hack for Firefox.

As you've stated, the simplest workaround for this is to have each page apply a unique class to the `html` or `body` element and select according to that class, whether via hardcoding, or dynamically.

Comment: Great answer! Manually naming classes everywhere is not that simple when you have lots and lots of pages. It's good to know about @document at-rule. Don't you also think its an useful implementation browsers should aim?

Comment: @Sarchophagi: Yes but it's either too difficult to implement or just not on their priority lists. I'd wager on the latter since Firefox seems to have no trouble getting the basics right...

Answer (score 0):

you could add and `id` atribute to the `body` tag and style things inside it using:

```
body#contact div{
background:#376;
color:#857;
/*etc*/
}
```

more information about selectors in http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/